# In C++, is a function automatically virtual if it overrides a virtual function?

Tags: c++, virtual, overriding

I would expect that if `foo` is declared in class `D`, but not marked virtual, then the following code would call the implementation of `foo` in `D` (regardless of the dynamic type of `d`).

```
D& d = ...;
d.foo();
```

However, in the following program, that is not the case. Can anyone explain this? Is a method automatically virtual if it overrides a virtual function?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C {
public:
        virtual void foo() { cout << "C" << endl; }
};

class D : public C {
public:
        void foo() { cout << "D" << endl; }
};

class E : public D {
public:
        void foo() { cout << "E" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        E& e = *new E;
        D& d = *static_cast<D*>(&e);
        d.foo();
        return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
E
```

Comment: The static_cast is superfluous - `D& d = *static_cast<D*>(&e);` is equivalent to `D& d = e;` due to the implicit cast from E*/E& to D*/D&.

Comment: In c++ 11 adding "override" to the function declaration makes it clear your intent to override the base class function. It also triggers an error from the compiler in case the function that you declare differs in constness from base (something that can surprise you in case you derive from std::exception for example and declar what() non-const)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Standard 10.3.2 (class.virtual) says:

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function vf with the same name and same parameter list as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides*
>
> [Footnote: A function with the same name but a different parameter list (clause over) as a virtual function is not necessarily virtual and does not override. The use of the virtual specifier in the declaration of an overriding function is legal but redundant (has empty semantics). Access control (clause class.access) is not considered in determining overriding. --- end foonote]

Answer (score 17):

Quick answer may be no, but correct answer is **yes**

C++ doesn't know about function hiding, so overriding virtual function without virtual keyword marks that function virtual too.

Comment: @Yossarian, that's why it's considered good practice to declare virtual functions in derived classes as virtual so that the intent is clear. Scott Meyers's discusses this in his Effective C++ book.

Comment: I've heard somewhere that not marking virtual in derived methods would make them virtually final. which makes the third level derivative a non-virtual override. but I find that Tadeusz 's standard's extract is proving this belief wrong because of the word `indirectly`, isn't it ?

Comment: @v.oddou "I've heard somewhere" that things people have "heard somewhere" are usually false. ;-) As long as there's a function with the same signature marked `virtual` _somewhere_ higher up in the hierarchy, then any derived function with the same signature is an override. 'Gaps' in whether the declaration included `virtual` aren't relevant, as again, the keyword has empty semantics after its most basal appearance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating any copy of the object of e and putting it in d. So d.foo() follows normal polymorphic behavior and calls derived class method. A method which is declared as virtual in the base class becomes automatically virtual in the derived class also.

Answer (score -1):

The output ("E") behaves exactly as one would expect it to behave.

The reason:
The dynamic (i.e. runtime) type of that reference is E. You are doing a static upcast to D, but that does not change the actual type of the object of course.

That's the very idea behind virtual methods and dynamic dispatches: You see the behavior of the type you were instantiating, which is E, in this case.